# FormType not returning proper value on Dynamics CRM 2016

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

[image]In javascript, I have written `Xrm.Page.ui.getFormType();`.

This code does not work when form is read-only.
Even though on the form it is written read-only on the bottom of the record, it is giving me formtype as 2.

even Onload  shows formtype 2 [image]

Comment: Don't know anything about dynamics CRM, but maybe [this thread](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/microsoft-dynamics-crm-forum/189423/about-xrm-page-ui-getformtype-in-crm-2016-on-premises) will be relevant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

Edit:

[Sounds like a bug in CRM 2016](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/microsoft-dynamics-crm-forum/189423/about-xrm-page-ui-getformtype-in-crm-2016-on-premises) (v8.2) - credit goes to @Alon in above comment.

---

I was able to test it quickly, like below.

**First scenario**:
Users' security role don't have Edit/Update privilege for that particular entity record. So the footer says, the record is **Active** and the form mode is **Read only**

`alert(Xrm.Page.ui.getFormType());` says 3

**Second scenario**:
That particular entity record is deactivated/disabled. So the footer says, the record is **Inactive** and the form mode is **Read only**. Applies to completed Activity record too.

`alert(Xrm.Page.ui.getFormType());` says 4

[image]

On a side note, `Xrm.Page` is deprecated. Have to re-write them using `formContext`.

```
formContext.ui.getFormType();
```

[Read more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/model-driven-apps/clientapi/reference/formcontext-ui/getformtype)

Comment: I am using V8.2 and this code has written on ProcessOnchange(BPF finish).

Comment: Is there any other way to get the formtype??

Comment: @amarbisht, In that case - the community thread bug (mentioned by Alon in comments above) fit your scenario.. we have to find workaround.. I dont have 8.2 version handy